# how to set svg pattern as html background

Tags: html, svg, background

I'd like to have a pattern I made in an embedded SVG appear as the background of an html doc.

```html
<head>
<style>
body{
    background-image: url('apattern.svg');
}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: OK, so what about the markup above is not working for you?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, SVGs do not work well in body-background as you described in the question, if at all.  What I've done is create a fallback option for those browsers that have an issue.

```
body {
  background: url(fallback.png);
  background-image: url(image.svg), none;
}
```

See ... http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/